# Displaying email size in apple mail Version 13.4?

Tags: mail.app, email

**Context**

In previous versions of Mail one could see the size of an email in Apple Mail.

**Question**

> Is it possible to recover this feature in Apple Mail 13.4 (MacOs Catalina)?

It seems that knowing the size of your email is useful, if only to avoid sending too large attachments?

Alternatively, how does one have access to the size of a given email?

Comment: Doesn't View>Show Message Size in Mail provide exactly what you want?

Comment: You can either answer the question yourself and mark it as resolved, or remove the question. Whatever fits you better :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jaume, the solution is in fact fairly trivial:

> View>Show Message Size in Mail

will display the size of each message.

I hope this post will be useful to someone like me who did not look at the correct place for the answer.